# Connecting to iseries DB2 database with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, db2, ibm-midrange

I've been having some difficulty connecting to an iseries DB2 database from a .net 4.0 application I'm developing. I've been trying to use the IBM.Data.DB2.dll library to connect to it using the following code;

```
String connectionString = "Database=[DBName];UserID=[UserID];Password=[Password];Server=[ServerName]";
connection = new DB2Connection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

When the `connection.Open()` command is run I receive the following error:

> ERROR [58009] [IBM] SQL30020N  Execution of the command or SQL
>   statement failed because of a syntax error in the communication data
>   stream that will affect the successful execution of subsequent
>   commands and SQL statements:  Reason Code "0x124C"("0100")"". 
>   SQLSTATE=58009

Does anyone know of another way of connecting to this kind of database in .net?

Comment: Might be a version mismatch between you DB2 client version, DB2 Connect version, and/or iSeries version.

Comment: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html

Comment: Could you suggest another way I can connect to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connString = "DataSource=SYSTEM;UserID=USER;Password=PASSWORD";
        iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        string cmdString = "CRTPF FILE(TESTLIB/TESTNET) RCDLEN(100)";
        string cmdText = "CALL QSYS.QCMDEXC('" + cmdString + "', " + cmdString.Length.ToString("0000000000") + ".00000" + ")";

        iDB2Command cmd = new iDB2Command(cmdText, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using Data Direct DB2 driver from Progress. This supports Entity Framework. May be you can try with that. You can download the evaluation version online (progress.com)